# 'addLayer' of undefined openlayers angular 4

Tags: angular6, openlayers

i want add marker by clicking on the map in openlayers angular 6, i want to use addLayer in my function but it doesn't work?

```
 this.map.on('click', function (e) {
  console.log(e.coordinate);
  var lonlat = e.coordinate;
  console.log(lonlat);

  var lon = lonlat[0];
  var lat = lonlat[1];
  this.startMarker = new Feature({

    geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([lon, lat])),

  });


  this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
      features: [this.startMarker]
    }),

  });

  this.map.addLayer(this.startMarker);

});
```

Comment: You are passing the wrong object as parameter.  It should be `this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer);`

Comment: I changed this mistake( this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer);), but it shows same error  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined

Comment: I don't understand how `this.map` can be undefined - surely it must exist for it to generate a click event?

Comment: I think `this` is redefined inside the event.  But you can keep the context by changing your final line to `}, this);`

Comment: unfortunately same error

Comment: It seems you cannot override `this` inside an event callback in OpenLayers 5 (unlike OpenLayers 4).  `this` probably is the map so try `this.addLayer(this.vectorLayer);`.  If that works you might want to reconsider using `this` anywhere in your code to avoid confusion.

Comment: in console log shows that this.map is undefined

Comment: Yes, `this` will be the map, so it's like saying `map.map`  @FatAl's method should work (but not on some versions of Internet Explorer), changing the last line to `}, this);` would have worked in earlier versions of OpenLayers but you could also replace the last line with `}.bind(this));` in any version and it should work on any browser.

Comment: }.bind(this)); working!!!,i have not errors but i cant add marker on map

Comment: It will be there, but in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the `this` binding and `addlayer()` parameter, the feature geometry needs to be in view coordinates.  `e.coordinate` is already in view coordinates, so you can use it directly

```
this.map.on('click', function (e) {

  this.startMarker = new Feature({
    geometry: new Point(e.coordinate),
  });

  this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({

    source: new VectorSource({
      features: [this.startMarker]
    }),

  });

  this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer);

}.bind(this));
```

Comment: This method works but for our part we use the latest standard ES6 and we use the arrows function at almost all sauces (Less code and more clear). Angular provides you with a file containing polyfill for IE. This allows you to use the latest ES6 standards such as arrow functions.

Comment: By not relying an a polyfill it should work for any OpenLayers application where the map has been defined inside an object, not only Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Try the arrow function to keep the context of `this`.

Your code sample should look like this:

```
this.map.on('click', (e) => {
  console.log('Keep the context of this.map: ', this.map);

  console.log(e.coordinate);
  var lonlat = e.coordinate;
  console.log(lonlat);

  var lon = lonlat[0];
  var lat = lonlat[1];
  this.startMarker = new Feature({
    geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([lon, lat])),
  });

  this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
      features: [this.startMarker]
    }),

  });

  this.map.addLayer(this.startMarker);

});
```